# Integrating KDevelop with MSYS2

Tags: msys2, kdevelop

I have been using KDevelop on Linux for a long time, and I really like its CMake integration. Also, on Windows, MSYS2 constitutes my favorite development environment. How can I use KDevelop with MSYS2? If I simply call KDevelop from MSYS2 shell, would it work? If it doesn't, what steps should be taken for their cooperation?

Answer (score 4):

KDevelop picks all information about the build from the build system. So, to use it with MSYS environment it is sufficient to make sure that CMake is able to use it. And for that to work, the simplest solution is, yes, start `kdevelop.exe` from MSYS shell. KDevelop process would inherit all environment variables of MSYS and forward them to CMake.

If you are using Custom Makefiles plugin the process is almost the same, you'd just need to set include directories manually.

If you encounter a bug or will need help, feel free to ask on `#kdevelop` channel on Freenode or create a PR on [bugs.kde.org](http://bugs.kde.org).